# How do I get ElasticSearch to parse the below information correctly?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash-grok

Please see the below code that I am trying to ingest into elastic search.
My goal is to get all the fields parsed out so that I can use them to filter data.

```
{
 "data": [
  {
   "type": "projection",
   "id": "2016597",
   "attributes": {
    "adjusted_odds": null,
    "board_time": "2024-02-16T17:00:00-05:00",
    "custom_image": null,
    "description": "NBASZN (27 Games Remaining)",
    "discount_percentage": 94,
    "end_time": "2024-02-22T21:00:00-05:00",
    "flash_sale_line_score": 0.5,
    "hr_20": true,
    "is_promo": true,
    "line_score": 9.5,
    "odds_type": "standard",
    "projection_type": "Single Stat",
    "rank": 0,
    "refundable": true,
    "start_time": "2024-02-22T21:00:00-05:00",
    "stat_type": "30+ Points Games",
    "status": "pre_game",
    "today": true,
    "tv_channel": null,
    "updated_at": "2024-02-16T17:01:34-05:00"
   },
   "relationships": {
    "duration": {
     "data": null
    },
    "league": {
     "data": {
      "type": "league",
      "id": "188"
     }
    },
    "new_player": {
     "data": {
      "type": "new_player",
      "id": "60344"
     }
    },
    "projection_type": {
     "data": {
      "type": "projection_type",
      "id": "2"
     }
    },
    "stat_type": {
     "data": {
      "type": "stat_type",
      "id": "363"
     }
    }
   }
  }
}
```

This is the current Grok pattern

```
%{QUOTEDSTRING:field}: "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{QUOTEDSTRING:field2}.*?%{QUOTEDSTRING:field3}.*?%{QUOTEDSTRING:field4}.*?%{QUOTEDSTRING:field5}.*
```

but it only parses certain fields, and majority of it gets added to the field named "message".

If someone can please assist me with this, I would be very grateful!